# Fetching data from multiples pages of API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm fetching data from a PS4 Games API but it's split into 400+ pages. I wanted to get the data from all pages, but the solution I came up with did not work very well. It gives me an error **'JSON Value  of type NSNull cannot be converted to a valid URL'**. Also, I don't think the for loop works well either, it shows me it going through all the pages when it displays the results in my list.

Additionally, this API is dynamic because new games keep getting released. So how could I get data up to latest page without manually changing my last page number everytime? I looked at some questions here but I couldn't fit it into my code

My code is rather long so I'm just going to post the part that matter:

```js
  componentDidMount() {

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < 400; i++) {

      fetch(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page=${i+1}&platforms=18`, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": "495a18eab9msh50938d62f12fc40p1a3b83jsnac8ffeb4469f"
        }
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          const { results: games } = json;
          this.setState({ games });
          //setting the data in the games state
        });
    }
  }
```

The API also has an item that gives me the link of the next page, I think there is a way to use 'next' and fetch data from that URL

If anyone could help, that would be AWESOME. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

its my first answer on this forum, so... I hope be helpfull.
For me you have 2 options:
Each request send 2 variables in the answer **count** and **next**, or you make a *for* loop with **count**/20 as limit (20 is the number of items gaves in the answer), or you make a *while* loop until the **next** variable give *null* as answer (currently at page 249).

Answer (score 0):

What is currently happening is you are making 400 requests and when each comes in it is overwriting the component with the response it received. It does not care about what is already there or any of the other requests.

An approach you could try instead is as the responses come in append the results to the ongoing list and update the state with the running list.

Going forward and for your other question about handling new releases. Instead of running 400 queries every time the application is used, try looking into caching the results. When the app loads you can see if cache exists and load or query if it does not. The rawg.io `/games` endpoint has a parameter for ordering by release. When the application loads in future you can conditionally loop until you reach a game that is already in cache at which point terminate.